# How to update a UICollectionViewCell Label?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, label, uilabel

I am trying to change a text label in a UICollectionViewCell, but for some reason it just will not update. Any help would be aprreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use didSet to make your code a bit reactive.

```
class CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell{
    
    var text = "" {
        didSet{
            self.label.text = text
        }
    }
    
    private var label : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

```
class CollectionViewClass : UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{
    
    var collectionView = UICollectionView()
    let id = "cell ID"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame)
        collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: id)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: id, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.text = "some text"
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
    }
}
```

In the above code, cell's text value is given everytime it's loaded. Whenever text is set, didset is called which updates the label value.

Comment: You'll also need to `addSubview(label)` right?

Comment: @aheze Yeah, I just quickly typed out the base code.

Comment: @Tom you need to have 2 classes. One for CollectionView and another for collectionviewCell